# On OSX, is it possible to access a Windows network drive without mounting it?

Tags: macos, smb

In windows you can refer to the path to the network drive, like //server/folder/ wherever you need to access it. On OSX we have been able to access the network drive by mounting it first, but I was wondering if it was possible to skip that step and reference the network location without mapping it on the OSX machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it without mounting by using `smbclient` which would feel similar to a ftp client.

See the [SMB HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SMB-HOWTO-8.html)